# Javascript datepicker popup?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm looking for a javascript datepicker like this one : http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/
but I want it to respect a maximum date (like the one mentionned in the "max" attribute of my date input on the web page). I don't care if I have to set that as an option but I want it to respect a certain date.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from 2.0 mobiscroll has this functionality. It also works with input type="date" min/max values.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery and jQuery UI offer this kind of functionnality, but they do not offer this layout.

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers nowadays you can just use:

```
<input name="mydate" type="date" max="2012-01-01"/>
```

It should default to the default date picker of the device you are using.

Comment: I'm using this mobile website in safari for iOS and the new (since iOS 5) datepicker that appear when focusing a date input does not respect the max attribute. So I'm looking for an alternate way to do this.